# Source Tree: Clone a repository which hosted in Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: git, repository, clone, sourcetree

I have two computer: PC and a Mac. Both installed the SourceTree. The PC already clone the repository hosted on Visual Studio Team Service website. When I cloned the repository on MAC mini, it prompted me a password field. I have typed in the same password as the one on PC but still having the pop up for password.

Does it only be connected by once SourceTree at a time?

Comment: Are you cloning via ssh or https? Check it at the beginning of the clone command.

Comment: I cloned with Https

Comment: @LittleFunny were you able to find a solution to this issue? If so please let me know. Thanks!